Is there a way to debounce a Svelte 5 $derived value?
I tried with:
let searchText = $derived(debounce((typedText) => typedText, 2000)(typedText));

But searchText is not assigned!

Reproduction with $derived: searchText is not assigned.

Reproduction with $effect(): searchText assignment is not debounced at all.



A debounce function must only be called once, otherwise one gets new instances with independent timeouts.
Using an $effect:
const update = debounce(v => searchText = v, 300);
$effect(() => update(typedText));

The logic could be wrapped to be compatible with $derived.by:
function debouncer(getter, wait, immediate) {
    let current = $state();
    const update = debounce(v => current = v, wait, immediate);
    $effect(() => update(getter()));

    return () => current;
}

let typedText = $state();
const searchText = $derived.by(debouncer(() => typedText, 300));


You can simply call a debounced function inside the setter of your variable. This does not use $derived but it achieves what you want:
export function useSearch() {
  let query = $state("");
  let result = $state([]);

  const debouncedSearch = debounce(
    (q: string) => {
      result = callSomeApi(q)
    },
    500,
  );

  return {
    // this will get bound to the text field
    get query() {
      return query;
    },
    set query(value) {
      query = value;
      // here's where we trigger our debounced function
      debouncedSearch(value);
    },
    get result() {
      return result;
    },
  };
}

